# Excel - condtional formatting based on multiple strings

Tags: excel

I would like to fill the cells **individually** from C to L based on the 7 lists on the right. Unfortunately this isn't working too well.

Not every cell is getting filled and others are filled wrong/double.

I select the cells for the conditional formatting for the deep red list based on this:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($M$2:$M$20; C2)))
```

I'd guess that here's a simple error in thought with the "C2"?. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Edit:

Link to the file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mtGdSlDCMdR1qXVU07Z-hGFyvtq21Hpb

Comment: Are you trying to shade each cell whose value appears in M2:M20? If so, try `=IFNA(MATCH(C2,$M$2:$M$20;0);FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right, I want to shade every cell individually from column C to L. Matching the strings in M2:M20. Your code gave me first an error. So I changed the , after C2 to ;. But after that, every fill in deep red vanished?

Comment: Apologies - try `=IFNA(MATCH(C2;$M$2:$M$20;0)>0;FALSE)` instead

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still not working. The fields in C to L stay unfilled. I have added a link to the file. In the rules of the conditioning formatting you can see, how I used your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional format rule you are using applies to the range $C:$L. The first cell in this range is C1; substitute C2 in your formula with C1 and it should work as desired.